# C# read csv, calculate something, export another csv

Tags: c#, date, csv, datatable, correlation

I am new to C#. I would like to know how I can do the following computations in an intuitive way in C#. How should I read the input csv file to facilitate the required computations? Do I read the csv into lists, arrays, datatable, etc.? There are null values in some cells. Since I am really new to C#, it is greatly appreciated if you could provide some examples. Thank you. :)

**Input:** 
I have an input csv file with format:

```
<p> // header: date, Y, X1, X2, X3, X4 </p>
<p> // value: yyyy-mm-dd, double, double, double, double, double </p>
```

So I have time series data of Y and all the X's. For each distinct date, I have many rows of Y and X's.

**Data processing:**
I would like to do the followings:

1. For each distinct date, compute correlations between Y and each X. The length of Y and X can differ in distinct date. So I will have corr(Y, X1), corr(Y, X2), corr(Y,X3) , corr(Y,X4) for each date.
2. For each distinct date, sort Y and get the rank of each row, e.g.

Y rank 

     10 1 
     50 4 
     20 2 
     30 3

After obtaining the ranks, they are used to compute a single quantity, say QUANTITY. (Each distinct date I will have one number of QUANTITY.)

**Output:**
After all the computations, I would like to export the results to another csv file with format:

```
<p> // header: date, corr(Y, X1), corr(Y, X2), corr(Y,X3), corr(Y,X4), QUANTITY </p>
<p> // value: yyyy-mm-dd, double, double, double, double, double </p>
```

Comment: I posted an answer that assumes the existence of outside functions, but I could fill it in a bit more if you could give the formula for `QUANTITY`. Is it not just a count of the records? And if it is, why do you need sorting and ranking involved?

Comment: Fair enough. Well then an external method is appropriate anyway, so I'll leave my answer as "simple" as possible and not include it.

Comment: Thanks so much man. Your code looks intuitive to me. :))

Comment: Glad to hear it. Let me know if any part of it doesn't work for you and you need some help, but aside from that, when you decide it works I would appreciate you marking it as an answer to take this off the unanswered queue. No rush. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here goes. First off, I'd use a Nuget package called [`CsvHelper`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper) to handle your parsing. It's super easy to use and effective. But for the purposes of example, I'll just split by commas for each record.

Let's say you have a file at path `string path = ...;` that contains the csv. First, we parse the CSV.

First, since you say there can be null values (although a CSV parser would handle this better), let's get a method.

```
private static double? getDoubleOrNull(string text)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        return null;
    else
        return double.Parse(text);
}
```

Now we can do the actual parse and use that method.

```
var records = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
                            .Skip(1) // the header
                            .Select(c =>
                                       {
                                           var fields = c.Split(',');

                                           return new
                                           {
                                               Date = DateTime.Parse(fields[0]),
                                               Y = getDoubleOrNull(fields[1]),
                                               X1 = getDoubleOrNull(fields[2]),
                                               X2 = getDoubleOrNull(fields[3]),
                                               X3 = getDoubleOrNull(fields[4]),
                                               X4 = getDoubleOrNull(fields[5]),
                                           };
                                       });
```

Done, alright, now we group by the date and find the result. I wasn't sure of how you want to correlate the data, so I've just assumed the existence of an `object corr(IEnumerable<double?> Y, IEnumerable<double?> X)` function. I also assumed the existence of `object getQuantity(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, double?>> ys)`, where the keys represent the 1-based ranks as you showed and the values represent the `Y` value from the original CSV.

```
var result = records.GroupBy(c => c.Date)
                    .Select(c => new
                                 {
                                     Date = c.Key,
                                     corr1 = corr(c.Select(x => x.Y), c.Select(x => x.X1)),
                                     corr2 = corr(c.Select(x => x.Y), c.Select(x => x.X2)),
                                     corr3 = corr(c.Select(x => x.Y), c.Select(x => x.X3)),
                                     corr4 = corr(c.Select(x => x.Y), c.Select(x => x.X4)),
                                     quantity = getQuantity(c => c.OrderBy(x => x).Select((x, index) => new KeyValuePair<int, double>(index + 1, x)))
                                  });
```

Now, I believe we should have our data to output. That makes it a relatively simple matter.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
{
    writer.WriteLine("date, corr(Y, X1), corr(Y, X2), corr(Y,X3), corr(Y,X4), QUANTITY");

    foreach(var v in result)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", v.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), v.corr1, v.corr2, v.corr3, v.corr4, v.quantity));
    }
}
```

You'll, of course, want to add in lots of error checking. And I might have made a typo or two since I did this all in the SO text editor, but it should be pretty easy to work out a final solution from this.

Comment: I got an error in the getDoubleOrNull function. Do you know what's wrong from this error message:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.getDoubleOrNull(string)'

Comment: Oh, if you're working in a static class you need to mark the method as static. Just prepend `static` to the method signature: `static double? getDoubleOrNull(string text)`. I've updated my answer to reflect that change.

Comment: Since I am new to object and query, I am not sure how to implement the method: object corr(IEnumerable<double?> Y, IEnumerable<double?> X). 
If the input argument is two arrays such as: 
double corr(<double> Y, <double> X){
...
return CORRELATION;
}

, 
I can understand it. 


Like this:
http://mantascode.com/c-how-to-get-correlation-coefficient-of-two-arrays/

Would you mind showing me how to really implement it? Also make sure if one of X or Y is null, the pair is discarded.

Comment: You mean `double corr(double[] Y, double[] X)`? That's easy enough. For each of my calls to `corr`, just make this change: Instead of `corr(c.Select(x => x.Y), c.Select(x => x.X1))`, do `corr(c.Select(x => x.Y).ToArray(), c.Select(x => x.X1).ToArray())`.

Comment: Yes intuitively the return type would be double given two arrays. How can I incorporate that into the query? If I am writing a function double corr(double[] Y, double[] X), then corr(c.Select(x => x.Y).ToArray(), c.Select(x => x.X1).ToArray()) will not be of the correct type??

Comment: Ah, yes. Here we have to deal with that pesky "some fields might not have data" part. Those `.ToArray()` calls will return `double?[]`s, but you want `double[]`s. How are you supposed to handle data that isn't given?

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to invent my own CSV parser - doing it right is suprisingly hard when you have to consider "escaped" strings, different field seperators (";"!) etc. pp.

I like the kbcsv library, which can easily read in csv and provide a datatable with the results:

http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am not allowed to use any external library. It would be great if there is a fast and easy way to do the parsing.